# Haskell Expected type: [t0 a0] Actual type: [a]

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch

```
data PossibleTuple a = Multiple (a, Int) | Single a

pack :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
{-
...
-}

encode_modified' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [PossibleTuple a]
encode_modified' [] = []
encode_modified' x = map (\x -> element x) (pack x)
    where
        element x
            | length x > 1 = Multiple (x, length x)
            | otherwise = Single x
```

I'm trying to do this:

```
encodeModified "aaaabccaadeeee"
[Multiple 4 'a',Single 'b',Multiple 2 'c',
 Multiple 2 'a',Single 'd',Multiple 4 'e']
```

but I get this error:

```
    * Couldn't match type `a' with `t0 a0'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          encode_modified' :: forall a. Eq a => [a] -> [PossibleTuple a]
        at src/Lib.hs:117:1-54
      Expected type: [t0 a0]
        Actual type: [a]
    * In the second argument of `map', namely `(pack x)'
      In the expression: map (\ x -> element x) (pack x)
      In an equation for encode_modified':
          encode_modified' x
            = map (\ x -> element x) (pack x)
            where
                element x
                  | length x > 1 = Multiple (x, length x)
                  | otherwise = Single x
    * Relevant bindings include
        x :: [a] (bound at src/Lib.hs:119:18)
        encode_modified' :: [a] -> [PossibleTuple a]
          (bound at src/Lib.hs:118:1)
    |
119 | encode_modified' x = map (\x -> element x) (pack x)
    |                                             ^^^^^^
```

Why would `pack x` need to have the type `t0 a0`? `x` is of type `a0` and thus `pack x` would have type `[a0]`.

All the types seem to match. The output of the `map` function is `PossibleTuple a0`. I don't even know where the `a0 t0` comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type do you suppose `element` has? You call `length` on its argument, meaning you think it takes a list as input. However, you also map it over a list of type `[a]`, meaning you think it can take any type `a` as input. This is a type mismatch.

Similarly you say you hope that your result will look like `[Multiple (4, 'a')]`, but your `element` function can never produce this result. The first element in each tuple is the `length` of the second element, and `length 'a'` is a type error.

The first thing I would do is re-examine the type of `pack`, though. It can't do anything with its current type that seems very relevant. Probably it should be `Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`. After that you will have more type errors to resolve, leading to a better definition of `element`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Multiple 4 'a'
```

This does not match the value constructor you defined. This is the constructor you defined

```
data PossibleTuple a = Multiple (a, Int) | Single a
```

So to construct `Multiple`, you should do `Multiple ('a', 4)`. Conversely, if you *want* to do `Multiple 4 'a'`, then your constructor should read

```
data PossibleTuple a = Multiple Int a | Single a
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `pack :: Eq a => [a] -> [[a]]`.

This function already exists, it is called `group`. It groups together consecutive elements of a list, which are equal to one another.

Then `element` needs just a small tweak to work,

```
    where
        element x
            | length x > 1 = Multiple (.... x, length x)
            | otherwise = Single (.... x)
```

with the same name appearing on both `....`s. Normally using that function is frowned upon but here it will be correct by construction.

Or you could use `@` patterns in pattern matching, like

```
    where
        element x@(h:_)
...........
```

This encoding is known as run-length encoding, in case you were wondering.

---

To easier see what's going on, it usually helps mentally if we name the *lists* by  variables in *plural*, like using `xs` for a list of `x`s (`xs` is to be read like it rhymes with "axes"):

```
encode_modified' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [PossibleTuple a]
encode_modified' [] = []
encode_modified' x = -- map (\x -> element x) (pack x)
                     map (\xs -> element xs) (pack x)
  where
  element xs
    -- | length x > 1 = Multiple (x, length x)    -- length of "x"??
       | length xs > 1 = Multiple ( x , length xs)  -- no, of "xs"!!
                                   ---
       | otherwise = Single x
                          -----
```

and the (underscored) plurality type mis-matches are now self-evident.